# Can I copy an R library directory from one windows PC to another?

Tags: r, windows, install.packages

I have two windows PCs, one on-line, one off-line.

I'd like to run R (3.5.1) on both.  (because it's another quantum of work to upgrade both sides to 3.5.2)

I need 176 or so packages (after using miniCRAN to find dependencies).

I'm building a local repo on the connected PC, and I can port this to the off-line machine, but I think I saw something on the RStudio site suggesting I might be able to just copy the library directory of the installed packages on the on-line PC.

What's the best approach?